# Имя якоря присвоить к id

Tags: javascript

В содержании страницы существует блок `div` с постоянным `id="links"` в котором дочерними элементами являются неизвестные ссылки (якоря).

**Экземпляр:**

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="#неизвестный якорь 1">1</a>
    <a href="#неизвестный якорь 2">2</a>
    <a href="#неизвестный якорь 3">3</a>
</div>
```

Неизвестные ссылки (якоря) генерируются **CMS**, и ведут на другой блок `div` с постоянным `id="content"`.

**Экземпляр:**

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="получить имя неизвестного якоря 1">
       Текст
  </div>
  <div id="получить имя неизвестного якоря 2">
       Текст
  </div>
   <div id="получить имя неизвестного якоря 3">
       Текст
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вопрос:**

Как с помощью **JavaScript** прочитать имя неизвестного якоря после решетки `#` в блоке `id="links"` и присвоить прочитанное имя к `id` в блоке `<div id="content">`.

P.S
Блоков с ссылками и текстом может быть несколько. Ссылок в блоке может быть и больше, до 10-ти.

Comment: `id` должен быть уникален. Почему у вас три `div`а с одным и тем  же `id`?

Comment: Peter Olson, изменил экземпляры.

Comment: Такое предположение, что Вы боретесь с последствиями, а не с причиной. Никак нельзя выдернуть эти `id` силами CMS?

Comment: soon, нельзя там всё в движке латинскими буквами генерируется, даже если в div вставить <?php get_url('id'), то нужно писать функцию на PHP, что для содержания не подходит. Простой способ прочитать и присвоить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPD:**

```
var linksDiv =  document.getElementById("links").getElementsByTagName('a'); // получаем все ссылки
var contentDiv = document.getElementById("content")getElementsByTagName('div'); // получаем все контент дивы
for(var i = 0; i < linksDiv.length; i++) {
   currentLinkText = linksDiv[i].href;
   contentDiv[i].id = currentLinkText.substr(currentLinkText.indexOf("#") + 1); // с учётом вашего "http://localhost/links.htm#content-one" 
}
```

Будет работать при условии, что кол-во ссылок и дивов с контентом одинаковое.

Comment: Это то что надо, а как сделать что бы id точно совпадал с ссылкой. Дело в том что id в содержании такого вида. id="ile:///D:/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%20%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0.htm#content-one"

Comment: Попробуйте так: `contentDiv[i].id = decodeURIComponent(linksDiv[i].href).substr(1, linksDiv[i].href.length);` Скорее всего там строка другая будет и `.substr(1, linksDiv[i].href.length)` нужно будет заменить

Comment: Декодировался URL, но чистого id нет.

Comment: Что получается в итоге-то? Дайте пример Id, что сейчас.

Comment: Вот: `<div id="ttp://localhost/links.htm#content-one">     
            <p>Текст</p>          
    </div>`

Comment: Хорошо, посчитаю за вас кол-во знаков, которые нужно обрезать: `.substr(27)`

Comment: или `.substr(linksDiv[i].href.indexOf("#") + 1)`

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25619/discussion-between-steper-and-viher).

Answer (score 0):

На всякий случай оставлю решение на jQuery. Метки нет, но наличие CMS благоволит подключенному jQuery:

```
$( "#links a" ).map( function( index, el ) {
    $( "#content div" )[index].id = el.href.replace( /^.*?#/, "" );
} );
```

Сниппет:

```js
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( "#links a" ).map( function( index, el ) {
        $( "#content div" )[index].id = el.href.replace( /^.*?#/, "" );
    } );
});
```

```css
#content div {
    margin-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links">
    <a href="#неизвестный якорь 1">1</a>
    <a href="#неизвестный якорь 2">2</a>
    <a href="#неизвестный якорь 3">3</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
   <div id="получить имя неизвестного якоря 1">
       Текст1 <a href="#links">Наверх</a>
  </div>
  <div id="получить имя неизвестного якоря 2">
       Текст2 <a href="#links">Наверх</a>
  </div>
   <div id="получить имя неизвестного якоря 3">
       Текст3 <a href="#links">Наверх</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ReinRaus, спасибо большое, но я не буду подключать большую библиотеку из-за ссылок. Нет решения на JS ну и ладно, буду думать как сделать по другому.